# Rotate image with @click in Vue2

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a refresh button on dashboard. I want to make it rotate `360` degrees.
How can I rotate image with **every click** on a refresh button?

This is the code I tried, it only work twice click:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    clicked: false,
  },
  methods: {
    rotation() {
      this.clicked = !this.clicked
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.clicked {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.12/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <img 
    src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/09f.png/fff" 
    @click="rotation" 
    :class="{ clicked }" 
    alt="refresh-icon-btn" 
  />
</div>
```

Comment: `clicked` is `true/false`, not the name of the calls, right?

Comment: right, it refer to `boolean`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be one of the approach, have a inline style to toggle between 0 & 360 deg and have a constant class for transition.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    deg: 0,
  },
  methods: {
    rotation() {
      this.deg += 360;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.transition {
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.12/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/09f.png/fff" @click="rotation" class="transition" v-bind:style="{transform: `rotate(${deg}deg)`}" alt="refresh-icon-btn" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can keep the same rotation direction?

Comment: @PennyLiu - Yes we can, please check the update.

Comment: Thank you. That is freaking awesome. Just a slight adjustment to your code. :style="{ transform: \`rotate(${deg}deg)\` }"

Comment: @PennyLiu - I agree. It's best to use a string literal when applicable. I have made the changes in the answer. I am glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a [class binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) to toggle the class on and off.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    isClicked: false,
  },
  methods: {
    rotation() {
      this.isClicked = !this.isClicked
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.image {
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.clicked {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.12/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <img 
    src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/09f.png/fff" 
    @click="rotation"
    class="image"
    :class="{ clicked: isClicked }" 
    alt="refresh-icon-btn" 
  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use `setTimeout` to remove the class after the animation

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    clicked: false,
    rotationDuration: 500
  },
  methods: {
    rotation() {
      this.clicked = !this.clicked
      setTimeout(() => this.clicked = !this.clicked, this.rotationDuration)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.clicked {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  transition: transform var(--rotation-duration) ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.12/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <img 
    src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/09f.png/fff" 
    @click="rotation" 
    :class="{ clicked }" 
    :style="`--rotation-duration: ${rotationDuration}ms`"
    alt="refresh-icon-btn" 
  />
</div>
```